# if there are rules

Tags: grammar

> I'm a newbie here and not meaning to be presumptuous ***if*** there are rules against discussions of language that could be deemed technical.

[Reference](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/stock-facility-of-21-7-million.3920347/#post-20066713)

---

I think that ***if*** is not natural, because the word "if" is used to say that one thing will happen depending on another thing happening.

I'd like to know what you think about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'If' is natural with the meaning 'whether' when asking or wondering **if** (or whether) one thing (e.g. a person being judged presumptuous) will happen depending on another thing happening (the person asking a certain question).

> if
>
> conjunction (WHETHER)
>
> used to introduce a clause, often in indirect speech, that shows two
> or more possibilities:
>
> *Mrs Kramer called half an hour ago to ask if her cake was ready.
>
> I don't care if he likes it or not - I'm coming!
>
> I was wondering if you'd like to come to the cinema with me this
> evening?*

[If (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/if)

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the meaning of "not meaning to be presumptuous ***if*** there are rules against discussions of language that could be deemed technical." in the OP.

Comment: Reverse it: "If there are rules against... I am not meaning to be presumptuous'. If there are no such rules, then I don't need to worry about being thought presumptuous. Two possibilities.